# Assembly language msdos source code equation between cluster and FAT

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, fat, floppy

Going through old MS dos source code on github, I found some peculiar comments as shown below.

```
;Now we must load the FAT from the disk. Here's how we    
;find out where it starts: 

;FAT cluster 0 = media descriptor = 0F0h
;FAT cluster 1 = filler cluster = 0FFh
;Cluster start = ((cluster number) - 2) * SectorsPerCluster 
+ (start of user) = (cluster number) + 31
```

Can anyone explain these?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Cluster start = ((cluster number) - 2) * SectorsPerCluster 
+ (start of user) = (cluster number) + 31

Comment: Why are we adding 31 here

Comment: What is the meaning of filler cluster

Comment: That 31 comes from the rest of the calculation, assuming that SectorsPerCluster is 1 and (start of user) is 33, and returns the sector number the cluster can be found on.  (On larger disks, clusters would contain multiple sectors but for small disks they were one sector per cluster.)

Comment: In the era of MSDOS v2, floppy media generally had 1 sector per cluster. `start of user` is 33. Cluster numbers start at 2. Think of the calculation as also being the same as `(cluster number-2) + 33 = (cluster number) + 31`.  So now the question is where did 33 come from? On such media the there is 1 sector for the boot record (sector 0), 2 FAT tables of 9 sectors each = 18 sectors, and 14 sectors for a root directory of 224 entries of 32 bytes each = (224 * 32)/512 = 14. Thus `start of user` = 1+(9*2)+14=33. The 31 comes from 33-2=31.